# How do I get testcafe-hammerhead to build so that I can contribute to it?

Tags: typescript, testing, gulp, automated-tests, testcafe

After a fresh clone of my fork and an npm install, I get complilation errors from the typescript transpile step.

```
$ ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js build
```

```
[10:17:55] Starting 'build'...
...
[10:17:58] Starting 'client-scripts-transpile'...
[10:17:58] Finished 'templates' after 80 ms
[10:17:59] Using gulpfile /Volumes/projects/testcafe-hammerhead/Gulpfile.js
[10:17:59] Starting 'worker:lint'...
[10:17:59] Starting 'lint-js'...
[10:17:59] Starting 'lint-ts'...
/Volumes/projects/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.d.ts(9,33): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NodeBuffer'.
/Volumes/projects/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.d.ts(11,80): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NodeBuffer'.
TypeScript: 2 semantic errors
TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
[10:18:05] 'client-scripts-transpile' errored after 6.87 s
[10:18:05] Error: TypeScript: Compilation failed
    at Output.mightFinish (/Volumes/projects/testcafe-hammerhead/node_modules/gulp-typescript/release/output.js:130:43)
    at /Volumes/projects/testcafe-hammerhead/node_modules/gulp-typescript/release/output.js:43:22
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
[10:18:05] 'build' errored after 9.82 s
```

Note, I'm on MacOS 10.15.2 if that helps. I am, however, able to successfully build the Testcafe project but just not this one.
Node v13.2.0
Npm 6.13.1

My ultimate goal is to see if I can submit a fix for an issue we raised about 3rd party cookie handling that we raised with the Testcafe team.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to clone the original testcafe-hammerhead repository and build it the same way? I've done it without any errors.

Comment: Good point. I just tried that and I get the same error... There must be some subtle environment difference like OS, node version, or something else that is causing this different behavior. I am not sure what to try.

Comment: Could you please output the `iconv-lite` module version?

Comment: It is installing iconv-lite@0.4.11

Comment: According to the provided error, the iconv-lite module is installed outside of the testcafe-hammerhead. Plus a separate installation of iconv-lite@0.4.11 does not contain lib/index.d.ts. Could you please try to clone the testcafe-hammerhead into an empty directory?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Npm was picking up node_modules from a parent directory that was there accidentally. Thanks!